# Extending a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a custom user model. This model has to extend another model and also link to built-in django User. Currently I have:

```py
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

class Profile(Entity):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

But when I try to create a user I get an error: `UNIQUE constraint failed: project_profile.entity_ptr_id`.

Do I need to add another function to create entity first? Or should I structure my models in another way?

Answer (score 1):

if you creating the Profile instance with User it already saved in the database if you use `create` method. you don't need to `save` seperatly.
ie the following `signls` is enough for saving and creating user profile instance

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OneToOne relation means that you can have only one profile per user.

Modify the code to

```
class Profile(Entity):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm not getting an error on the profile. The error is on the entity. I need the profile to be associated with only one user.